# What is the default RAID-50 stripe size on a Dell EqualLogic PS6510?

Tags: raid, configuration, storage-area-network, dell-equallogic

We have a Dell EqualLogic PS6510 RAID Array.  I have full access to the web-based "PS Group Manager" app, as well as the "SAN Headquarters" app.  I have hunted high and low, and searched Google for the answer, but I cannot for the life of me determine the stripe size of the RAID-50 array we have configured.

Does anyone with experience on an EqualLogic PS6510 know how to find the stripe size?

---

Additional Info:

Page 19 of http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/business/solutions/engineering-docs/en/Documents/dvs-enterprise-reference-arch-citrix-blades-shared.pdf talks about the default stripe size being 64K.

Comment: Why are you using RAID 50?

Comment: Because it provides the RAID characteristics we identified as important at install.

Comment: So you're not fond of your data integrity and any other option was too fast? I'm not being nasty but who uses R50 over R10?

Comment: Thanks for that constructive help.  It's unfortunately a bit late to change to RAID 10 now, without reformatting the entire SAN.  Besides that, RAID 50 provides higher data capacity than RAID 10.

Comment: Raid 50 is supported by the company that engineered, sold, and supports this box. That's all that matters.

Comment: @MaxVernon Have you asked Dell?  One would hope they'd know...

Comment: I've looked at Dell's support site, and have looked at the online help for the SAN itself, no luck.  We have a question in to Dell, and are waiting for an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I found an [oracle tuning guide](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:kboWQXP6cuYJ:en.community.dell.com/dell-groups/dtcmedia/m/mediagallery/20059328/download.aspx%20&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShPM7UrwjhzdW-bEyqcDTcbKfZa4HFoTi3DWqvhoIe_A3MF-uxF0m212BsKaxWzJW4KpDwQp79MxB-9WVoiNegHOk13HTAWAHvUCwlZP5yEC1G-IjyKiRSojM9h1XWp-9fXlpd6&sig=AHIEtbTSS2RUG2U-uRcvcpSIlj6weJ-Umw) (google docs link) that seemed to imply 1MB stripes, but I also found a [blog post](http://www.spoonapedia.com/2010/04/dell-equallogic-san-experience-review.html) claiming that replication is done on 512k blocks.

Comment: That's been my experience too; no definitive answers!

Comment: If you talk to whoever sold this to you, you can probably get them to show you some sort of low level control panel, or maybe they'll just know. I suspect it'll be a fixed stripe size, though, based on architecture for similar boxes I know a bit better. In any case, escalate this at dell :) You pay a premium for support, and this counts!